# Purpose of weakref in MySQL mysql.connector.cursor

Tags: python, mysql

By using MySQL official python driver **mysql.connector**, the following code snippet works properly.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(...)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(...)
```

However when I used chained call to create cursor,

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import mysql.connector

cursor = mysql.connector.connect(...).cursor()

cursor.execute(...)
```

I got exception: **ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists**

It is due to the use of **weakref** in `mysql.connector.cursor` source code

```
def _set_connection(self, connection):
    """Set the connection"""
    try:
        self._connection = weakref.proxy(connection)
        self._connection._protocol  # pylint: disable=W0212,W0104
    except (AttributeError, TypeError):
        raise errors.InterfaceError(errno=2048)
```

The weakref won't increase the reference count to the temporary connection object, so that after statement

```
mysql.connector.connect(...).cursor()
```

connection object seemed to be recycled by garbage collection.

Since in `mysql.connector.connection` source code, there is no reference to cursor object.

The weakref in `mysql.connector.cursor` might not be set for solving circular reference issue.

Does anyone know about why to set weakref to reference to cursor's connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the revision history of the project, [the commit that introduces the use of `weakref`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/myconnpy/1.0/revision/201) simply says this:

> - Most objects now use weak references: there was no bug or leak which showed we needed to doso however. Can be revereted.

So it seems this was just a precautionary decision to avoid *potential* bugs or leaks, rather than a change that addressed a specific issue.

Comment: Did you use `bzr annotate` to find the commit?

Comment: @unutbu I actually used the "view with revision information" option in the Launchpad source viewer, but I'm sure that's just using `bzr annotate` under the covers.

Comment: @dano
I didn't notice that launchpad has complete commit history.
Thank you.